# javascript prompt number and continue prompting if answer is wrong

Tags: javascript, prompt

I need prompt the visitor for an integer between 1 and 100 and to **continue prompting** until a valid number is entered.

Here is what I have:

```
<script>

var number = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number from 1 to 100", ""));

if (number < 100) {
    document.write("Your number (" + number + ") is matches requirements", "");
} else if (isNaN(number)) {
    parseInt(prompt("It is not a number. Please enter a number from 1 to 100", ""));
} else {
    parseInt(prompt("Your number (" + number + ") is above 100. Please enter a number from 1 to 100", ""));
}

</script>
```

It recognizes the number but fails to re-ask when the number is wrong. Can you please help me and explain what you added?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 12):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
do{
    var selection = parseInt(window.prompt("Please enter a number from 1 to 100", ""), 10);
}while(isNaN(selection) || selection > 100 || selection < 1);
```

Comment: Add a radix parameter of 10 to the parseInt function and you're good to go :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a recursive approach:

```
var number = (function ask() {
  var n = prompt('Number from 1 to 100:');
  return isNaN(n) || +n > 100 || +n < 1 ? ask() : n;
}());
```

Comment: Better avoid recursion where not necessary. A loop like in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15047174/1162143 is simpler - a good thing!

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
<html>
    <head> </head>
    <body onload="promptForNumber();">


<script>
    function promptForNumber( text)
{
    if(text == '' ){
     text = "Please enter a number from 1 to 100";   
    }
    var number = parseInt(window.prompt(text, ""));
    checkNumber(number);

}
function checkNumber(number){

    if (number <= 100 && number >= 1) {
    document.write("Your number (" + number + ")  matches requirements", "");
} else if (isNaN(number)) {
    promptForNumber("It is not a number. Please enter a number from 1 to 100", "");
} else {
    promptForNumber("Your number (" + number + ") is not between 1 and 100", "");
}

}


</script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function myFunction(id) {

        let person = prompt("Please Enter Your Quotation");
        if (person != null) {
            if(person>=0||person<0){
                alert("max");
            }else{
            alert('Only Number is Allowed');
            myFunction(id)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
    age = prompt("Enter your age:");
    while(isNaN(age)){
        age = prompt("Enter your age in numerals only:");
    };
    function check(age){
        if(age>=21 && age<=80){
            document.write("You can vote.");
        }else if(age>=81){
            document.write("We'll come home to take your vote.");
        }else{
            document.write("You can not vote.");
        };
        return(age);
    }; 
    console.log(check(age));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 const handleCommissionRate = (id: number) => {
        const rate = prompt('Komisyon oranını girin') as unknown as number
        if (isNaN(rate)) {
            return handleCommissionRate(id)
        }
        console.log(id)
    }
```

this is my example function