# How do I convert this if statement to a while or a do-while loop?

Tags: javascript

I am using Javascript and was wondering how to convert this to a loop. So an if statement only allows one pass. I want to change it to a loop so that that if I keep entering a number higher than 8 my program will keep re-running the prompt. In an if statement, after the wrong first try, my program displays: 
The value entered is too large 
Value of n = 9
Value of A[9] = undefined 
I want to do it so that it keeps making you run the program until you enter a number 1-8 because thats how many var A I have.
Here is the coding:

```
var A = [1,12,23,34,45,56,67,78], maxlen = A.length;
var n = prompt("What element number do u want to access");
if (n >= 0 && n < A.length)
    {
    document.write("Value of n = ", n, "<br \>", "Value of A[", n, "] = ", A[n]);
    }
else {
    document.write("The value entered is too large <br \>");
    n = prompt("Max length is "+maxlen+"\n What element number do you want to access");
    document.write("Value of n = ", n, "<br \>", "Value of A[", n, "] = ", A[n]);
```

Comment: The concept "convert an `if` statement to a loop" doesn't really make a lot of sense.

Comment: Explain what you're trying to achieve along with the expected output.

Comment: Question does not make sense, also you should use `parseInt(prompt())`

Comment: Just edited the question! Hope that helps and sorry for the unclearness of the previous unedited question.

Comment: It's not that unclear if you look at the code, they're asking for the program to continuously re-prompt until it gets valid input. Here, T. Bui, try something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15047174/2374028

Comment: @crclayton Thats exactly it!

Comment: var A = [1,12,23,34,45,56,67,78], 
        maxlen = A.length,
        n = 0 ;

    while(n != -2 ){
      n = prompt("What element number do u want to access, you can exit by typing -1") - 1;

      if (n != -2 && n >= 0 && n + 1 < A.length)
        {
        document.write("Value of n = ", n, "<br \>", "Value of A[", n, "] = ", A[n]);
        }
      else if (n != -2 && n >= 0 && n + 1 > A.length) {
          document.write("The value entered is too large <br \>");
          n = prompt("Max length is "+maxlen+"\n What element number do you want to access") - 1;
      }
           
    }

Comment: @FurkanOrhan I tried your coding and it wouldn't work. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure ? Just press ctrl+alt+j and paste the code to the console. I just tried again and it works fine. Also you can examine the code to understand.

Comment: @FurkanOrhan Oh I just forgot a } to close the else if statement. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @FurkanOrhan Quick question, Why do you need the -1 at the end of n=prompt() -1;? I don't understand what that does

Comment: Because you shouldn t expect the user to type 0 as a number , where 0 is the first element on array to call as A[0] but the user should ask the first element as 1 , right ? So we are just taking the number and extracting 1 . Hope this helps !

Comment: @FurkanOrhan Makes sense! Thanks for the help!