# Javascript: Creating loop to check variable if its an int

Tags: javascript, loops, typeof

I have a variable that prompts a question. I want to make sure that the person answers with numbers and not "five." But also give an alert message that its not a valid number, and to ask the question again. I am still new and believe I did it incorrectly. Here is what I have so far.

```
var question = prompt("Enter a number");
for(i=0; i = question; i++){
    if{
        typeof question != "number");
        console.log("question not number");
        alert("Please try again");
}
```

Comment: Your if is using an open `{` instead of an `(`, and has a semicolon, rather than using `{}`'s

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, first you have a syntax error and second this will cause the loop to execute indefinetly.

Comment: This question is very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15047140/javascript-prompt-number-and-continue-prompting-if-answer-is-wrong/15047174

Answer (score 2):

You can make a function for asking the question. If the answer does not satisfy you you can call again this function from itself.

```
var askQuestion = function() {
    var response = prompt("Enter a number");

    // if it is good, return true (insert your condition in the if)
    if(true) {
        return true;
    }
    // If it is not good, recall the function, so it recall the question
    else {
        return askQuestion();
    }
}
```

Then in your code, do something like this :

```
if(askQuestion()) {
    // The person answered what you want
} 
// There is no else because it prompt the question all the time 
// if the answer is not what you are excepting
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a value is numeric parsing it with [`parseInt()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) and then actually checking if it's a number with [`isNaN()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp). This will work:

```
var question = prompt("Enter a number");
if (isNaN(parseInt(question))) {
    console.log("question not number");
    alert("Please try again");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A way with a loop until the input is an integer:

```
var question;
while (isNaN(parseInt(question = prompt("Enter a number"))))
{
   console.log("Question is not a number");
   alert("Please try again");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [isNaN()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp) to check if the user input is not a number. That means you can use !isNaN() to check if the user input is a number.

```
function isValidAns(ans){
    if(isNaN(ans)) return false;
    if(ans == 5) return false;

    return true;
}
```

You might also want a while loop to let user input again and again until the input is valid.

```
var ans = "";
while(true){
    ans = prompt("Enter a number");
    if(isValidAns(ans)){
        break;
    }else{
        alert("Please try again.")
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your solution.