# How do I loop back to the prompt if answer is incorrect?

Tags: javascript

How do I loop back to the prompt question if the user enters the wrong answer and I want the question to repeat until they get the correct answer?

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script>
    </script>
    <title> Javascript program</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        var company = (prompt("What the name of the company that developed the javascript language?", ""));
        if (company == 'netscape') {
            alert("correct answer!");

        } else {
            alert("wrong answer");

        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have a look at a [`while`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while) loop. BTW, what happens if someone types `Netscape` instead of `netscape`.

Comment: to add to the answers, you could also use a do while loop [as shown here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15047140/javascript-prompt-number-and-continue-prompting-if-answer-is-wrong#answer-15047174)

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap your code in a function and call self on incorrect value.

```js
var max_count = 5;

function showConfirm() {
  var company = (prompt("What the name of the company that developed the javascript language?", ""));
  if (company == 'netscape') {
    alert("correct answer!");
  } else {
    alert("wrong answer");
    // to limit user for limited count
    if (--max_count > 0)
      showConfirm()
  }
}
showConfirm();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [`while`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while) loop and loop forever until your condition is `true` and then use a [`break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) statement to exit the loop.

Basically, you could select loop which checks a condition **first**

```
while (condition) {
    // code
}
```

loop which checks a condition **later**

```
do {
    // code
} while (condition);
```

a solution inbetween

```
while (true) {
    // code
    if (condition) break;
    // code
}
```

or a recursive solution, like

```
function fn() {
    // code
    if (condition) {
        // code
        return
    }
    fn(); // call fn again
}
```

But I suggest to use an iterative approach until a value met a condition.

```js
var company;

while (true) {
    company = prompt("What the name of the company that developed the javascript language?", "");
    if (company === 'netscape') {
        break;
    }
    alert("wrong answer");
}
alert("correct answer!");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a loop like so:

```
let question = "What is the name of the company that developed the javascript language?",
    defaultAnswer = "stackoverflow",
    correctAnswer = "netscape";

while(prompt(question, defaultAnswer) !== correctAnswer) alert("Wrong answer")
alert("Correct answer");
```

Or you could use recursion, refer to Rajesh's answer.

Answer (score 0):

you need to include the function in itself until it meets the requirement and return(exit the function);

```
ask();
function ask(){
    var answer=prompt("Question..?");
    if(answer=="netscape"){
        alert("correct");
        return;
    }
    alert("wrong answer");
    ask();  
}
```

Comment: You do not need `else` and `ask()` should be after definition.

Comment: yeah, it's even neater without else block

Answer (score 0):

**showing prompt continuously can be irritating** and user always have option in **Chrome** to **prevent a page from creating more dialogues**. If you use a loop with `while(true)` and user opt to prevent dialogue out of irritation then your **page can end up in a hang state**. I would suggest to **use a counter to ask questions for a specific number of time** before assuming that answer is wrong as in below code

```
function askQuestion() {
    return prompt("What the name of the company that developed the javascript language?", "");
}

var counter = 0;
var correctAnswer = false;
while(!correctAnswer && counter < 10) {

    counter++;
    correctAnswer = askQuestion() === 'netscape';

    if (!correctAnswer) {
        alert("wrong");
    }
}

if (correctAnswer) {
    alert("correct");
} else {
    alert("sorry after 10 attempts answer is still wrong");
}
```

You can also check this plnkr link https://plnkr.co/edit/IbUFRC0HepfSHlvNqMzM?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I hope this short function with a couple of conditions helps anyone who needs to check if a certain piece of data is a number and if it is within a given range. I used it for dates, but you can pretty much use it for any kind of date-related data.

```
const checkData = function (data, value1, value2) {
 let x = (+prompt(`Choose the first date's ${data}. You can choose from ${value1} to ${value2}.`));
 if ((x < value1 || x > value2) || Number.isFinite(x) === false) {
  while ((x < value1 || x > value2) || Number.isFinite(x) === false) {
   x = (+prompt(`Criteria have not been met. You must type a number between ${value1} and ${value2}`))
  }
 }
 return x;};
checkData('month', 1, 12);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).