# Accept whole numbers from prompt, not decimals

Tags: javascript

My code works fine but I don't want it to accept decimals as well

```
var choice = parseInt(prompt("Please enter 1 , 2 or 3:"));
if (choice == 1) {
  var choice = 1
} else if (choice == 2) {
  var choice = 2
} else if (choice == 3) {
  var choice = 3
} else if (choice > 3) {
  var choice = 3
  document.write("<p>Please enter 1 , 2 , or 3:</p>")
} else if (choice < 1) {
  var choice = 3
  document.write("<p>Please enter 1 , 2 , or 3:</p>")
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript prompt number and continue prompting if answer is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15047140/javascript-prompt-number-and-continue-prompting-if-answer-is-wrong)

Comment: A bit aside, variables are declared only once, you don't need `var` in front of every assignment. And `document.write` is not purposed to manipulate DOM, don't use it.

Comment: As Pranjali Patil stated in their answer, you can't effect on the input of `prompt`, you can only edit the output result. If you want to filter the input, you need a real HTML element, like `<input type="number">`.

Answer (score 0):

prompt only takes two attributes, message and default.
also

> Please note that result is a string. That means you should sometimes cast the value given by the user. For example, if their answer should be a Number, you should cast the value to Number. ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt

I don't think we can make prompt to only take number or more specifically real numbers as input.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use `!Number.isInteger(+choice)`** (The `+` is the [unary plus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus))

Also, your code may seem to work fine, but it will only prevent bad input once. For example, if you try to type `0` twice, it will accept it. Instead, you want a [loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Looping_code) of some sort. The typical loop to use for this is a [do...while loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/do...while). I've created an example below.

```js
let choice = 0
do {
  choice = prompt('Please enter 1, 2, or 3:')
} while (choice > 3 || choice < 1 || !Number.isInteger(+choice))
const intChoice = parseInt(choice)
console.log(intChoice)
```

To make this more reusable, I would recommend wrapping some of this logic with a [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Function), too. (The [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) in the example below is just my preference)

```js
const intPrompt = () => {
  let choice = 0
  do {
    choice = prompt('Please enter 1, 2, or 3:')
  } while (choice > 3 || choice < 1 || !Number.isInteger(+choice))
  return parseInt(choice)
}

console.log(intPrompt())
```